# python script that captures an image and compares it to another image

Tags: python

Basically, I want to automate something. I would capture a 100x50 picture of a certain button, and have a script that takes a picture of the same area with the same size, and then compares the two pictures to see if they are different. If they are different, it would do nothing, if they are similar +/- a certain amount, it would then click it.

I have the screen capture kind of worked out, I just don't know how to compare them with PIL. I have done a lot of googling without success.

Comment: Define "similar +/- a certain amount."  Is it OK if the two images represent the same foreground shifted by a bit, or OK if the same images are the same except for the text of the button, for instance?  It might be helpful to know what you are trying to automate.

Comment: Just similar enough to know that the button has appeared, bot not an entirely different color or anything. I know it's not realistic for them to be exactly the same. It's a game, I used to have an autoit script for it, but autoit can't do image comparing or anything like that.

Comment: I have no idea what that is. God this is so daunting, maybe programming isn't for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pylab.imread` to easily read an image into a NumPy array:

```
In [3]: import scipy, pylab

In [4]: x = pylab.imread('example.jpg')

In [5]: x.shape
Out[5]: (480, 640, 3)
```

You can view the image, or any subset thereof:

```
In [6]: pylab.imshow(x)
Out[6]: <matplotlib.image.AxesImage at 0x98e564c>

In [7]: pylab.show()
```

If you wanted to compare two 8-by-8 blocks (say, the top left block of the red and blue layers), you could compute the mean squared error:

```
In [8]: x[:8,:8,0]
Out[8]: 
array([[147, 143, 146, 144, 146, 148, 146, 149],
       [145, 142, 146, 145, 147, 149, 148, 151],
       [143, 141, 146, 145, 147, 147, 148, 150],
       [143, 143, 146, 146, 146, 145, 147, 148],
       [147, 147, 147, 148, 147, 145, 146, 146],
       [146, 147, 145, 147, 148, 145, 147, 146],
       [146, 147, 144, 147, 147, 144, 146, 144],
       [147, 148, 144, 147, 147, 144, 146, 144]], dtype=uint8)

In [9]: x[:8,:8,1]
Out[9]: 
array([[125, 121, 122, 120, 118, 120, 116, 120],
       [123, 120, 122, 122, 119, 121, 118, 122],
       [122, 120, 123, 122, 120, 120, 118, 121],
       [122, 122, 123, 122, 120, 118, 117, 119],
       [124, 123, 123, 124, 121, 119, 119, 119],
       [122, 123, 120, 122, 121, 119, 119, 119],
       [121, 122, 116, 119, 119, 117, 119, 117],
       [122, 122, 115, 118, 119, 116, 119, 117]], dtype=uint8)

In [10]: def mse(x, y):
   ....:     return scipy.mean((x.astype(float)-y)**2)

In [11]: mse(x[:8,:8,0], x[:8,:8,1])
Out[11]: 676.0625
```

Comment: Wow. I seriously have no idea what to do with this, I'm a complete noob.

Comment: NumPy/SciPy is a popular Python package for numerical computing. Matplotlib/Pylab is a plotting package that is compatible with NumPy. If you want to do signal/image processing (which seems to relate to your question), SciPy might be worth installing. Here, I am reading an image into an array (like you might do in Matlab with `imread`). Once it's there, you can just treat it like a matrix, e.g. add/subtract matrices, etc.

Comment: So are scipy and numpy the only libraries I need to import at the start?

Comment: Sorry about that. In this example, `scipy` and `pylab`. Edited. I actually think it's possible entirely in `scipy` using `scipy.misc.imread`.

Comment: how would I change it if I just used scipy.misc.imread? I seriously have no idea what this stuff does. Thanks for your patience.